# Error setting Control Value within asp:ListView LayoutTemplate

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but my code is clearly not working.  I have my list view doing everything that I need, except that when I use the `ListView.FindControl()` method, and then set a property on that control, it give me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.  Here is my code:

ASPX

```
<p class="rates-title"><span>
            <asp:Literal ID="currentDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br>
            Todays Rates</p>
        <span class="rates-arrow sprite"></span>
        <asp:ListView ID="RatesList" ItemPlaceholderID="RSSPlaceholder" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RSSPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="AllRatesLink" CssClass="all-rates" runat="server">
                        View All Rates<span></span>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <div class="rate-text">
                        <p><%# Eval("Name") %></p>
                        <div class="rate">
                            <p><%# Eval("InitialRate") %>%</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%# Eval("Apr") %>
                    <a href="#rates-box-<%# Eval("Id") %>" class="todays-rates-click-side sprite"></a>
                    <div class="todays-rates-rollover">
                        <p><%# Eval("ContentTruncated") %></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
        currentDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yy");
        HyperLink allRatesLink = (HyperLink)RatesList.FindControl("AllRatesLink");
        allRatesLink.Text = "hello";
```

So the weird thing is that `currentDate` works just fine, the data that I use (elsewhere in my codebehind) works just fine for iterating through the list, but as soon as I set any property on the `allRatesLink` control, it gives the object reference not set error.  Any ideas/help on this one?

Comment: Where does the codebehind code reside?  Is it after the DataBind() call for the ListView?  It seems like the LayoutView isn't created yet and your FindControl is returning null.  You either need to do it after DataBind() or inside an OnLayoutCreated handler.

Comment: @LUKE, please make this an answer so I can choose it.  I wasn't doing it after the DataBind(), and that was the issue.  Thank you so much for catching that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

allRatesLink is null because it is not being found which leads to the Object reference error when you try to set a property of null.

You need the FindControl to be called after the LayoutTemplate is created such as in the OnLayoutCreated handler or after DataBind()